# One tinymce editor with content split into multiple parts

Tags: javascript, html, css, tinymce, editor

I am looking for a way to "split" tinymce content into multiple pieces. I don't exactly know how to explain it as it could be the reason why I have found nothing about my precise problem on internet but I'll give it a try.

I want to use tinymce as a blog post editor. To fill it I use JS and websocket linked to some functions that grab the content I want to put in. My only problem is that each of my posts are separated in 3 parts :

- The introduction
- The parts (headings) and the content of each part
- The conclusion

I started by using a simple tinymce editor but the problem is that I need to treat separately the 3 pieces. 1nd given the fact that everything is linked together, I can't.

That is why now I've changed everything by creating one textarea for introduction, one tinymce editor for the parts and one textarea for conclusion like this :
[THE LAYOUT I HAVE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9HGX.png)

But there also are big problems here because :

1. I can't use html in textareas
2. When i scroll in the editor the introduction textarea always stays on top of it as it is a different field (same for the conclusion when scrolling from the bottom of the page)
3. The design is not really good

I thought about using 3 tinymce editors but it does not solve the point 2.

So that's why I wanted to ask : is there a way to just "split" the content of a tinymce in multiple fields, or like create one tinymce editor out of multiple textareas ? So that I could get back my ancient design (image below) but with "separated" zones so that my JS functions can quickly detect if they are empty or not/quickly add content in them etc.

[THE LAYOUT I WANT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIi6o.png)

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.